# Check the formula of SDNF. JS

Tags: javascript, string, text, formula

There is a code in JS where a string (a logical formula) is received at the input and it is necessary to determine whether this logical formula is SDNF.

```
function isSDNF(formula) {
  // Step 1: check that the formula consists only of logical operations "and", "or" and "not"
  const validOps = ['&', '|', '!'];
  const invalidOps = formula.replace(/[A-Z!()]/g, '').split('').filter(op => !validOps.includes(op));
  if (invalidOps.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Step 2: Check that each operand of the formula is a variable or a negation of a variable
  const validVars = formula.match(/[A-Z]/g) || [];
  const validNegVars = formula.match(/!\w/g) || [];
  const invalidOperands = formula
    .replace(/[^A-Z!()]/g, '')
    .split(/[\(\)]+/)
    .flatMap(subformula => subformula.split(/[\&\|]+/))
    .filter(operand => !(validVars.includes(operand) || validNegVars.includes(operand)));
  if (invalidOperands.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Step 3: check that each disjunct (term) of the formula contains all variables (or their negations)
  const terms = formula.replace(/[()]/g, '').split('|');
  const termVars = terms.map(term => term.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []);
  const termNegVars = terms.map(term => term.match(/!\w/g) || []);
  const allVars = [...new Set(termVars.flat().concat(termNegVars.flat()))];
  if (!termVars.every(vars => vars.length === allVars.length) ||
      !termNegVars.every(vars => vars.length === allVars.length)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Step 4: check that each disjunct (term) of the formula contains at most one variable or its negation
const termInvalid = terms.some(term => {
  const termVars = term.match(/[A-Z]/g) || [];
  const termNegVars = term.match(/!\w/g) || [];
  const allVars = [...new Set(termVars.concat(termNegVars))];
  return allVars.length > 1;
});
if (termInvalid) {
  return false;
}


  
  // If all the steps are completed successfully, the formula is SDNF
  return true;
}

console.log(isSDNF("(((!A)&B)| (A&(!B)))")); // true
```

It outputs the wrong thing at all. I think the mistake is that the script takes into account spaces here. And I don't have to take them into account. I can't figure out where the error is in the formulas. Here are all the tests:

```
(((!A) / \B)\/(A/\(!B))) - true
(((!A) / \B)\/((A/\(!B))\/(((!A) / \(!B)))) - true
((A/\(B/\C))\/(A/\((!B) / \C)) - true
((A/\(B/\C))\/((A/\((!B) / \C))\/(((!A) / \((!B) / \(!C))))) - true
((And \/((!B)\/(!C)))\/(((!A)\/(B\/C)) - false
(A/\B)\/(A/\C)) - false
(A/\B/\C)\/(A/\C)) - false
(A\/B)\/(A\/B) - false
```